# App crashes in IOS 9 at AVPlayer TimeControlstatus

Tags: xamarin.ios, crash, avplayer

My app works in iOS 10 , but crashes at the below line

```
ViewModel.IsPlaying = (player.TimeControlStatus == AVPlayerTimeControlStatus.Playing
                || player.TimeControlStatus == AVPlayerTimeControlStatus.WaitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate);
```

with error

> -[AVPlayer timeControlStatus]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16fc83f0 An unhandled exception occured.

this is happening below ios 10, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that `timeControlStatus` is only available starting iOS 10.

As [Kris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180457/app-crashes-in-ios-9-at-avplayer-timecontrolstatus/42191951?noredirect=1#comment71545793_42191951) mentions, the following conditions seem to be very similar:

```
(player.timeControlStatus == .playing) == (player.rate != 0.0)
```

Comment: I am currently using player.rate and its working fine